# Magento 1.7 sorting by ordered quantity - bestseller products issues

Tags: php, magento

There are several cases reported where the standard solution(s) for this query do not work (similar questions on SO are abunding,with no definitive solution whatsoever).

What one would do to retrieve a collection of "bestsellers" is to use this query builder:

```
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection');

    $collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

    $collection = $collection
        ->addFieldToFilter('*')
        ->addOrderedQty()
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
        ->setPageSize(10)
        ->setCurPage(1);
```

Now, the `$collection` result holds some bogus values and it's missing important attributes altogether (no name, price, etc.). I cannot even try [this core-code workaround](http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/bestsellers-list-vs-flat-product-catalog-in-magento) in 1.7.

Could anyone please post a solution that is Magento 1.7 verified/certified/tested? (or the latest Magento release).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may or may not work for you, it might not be the most efficient way, but it does the job for me so here it is merged with parts of your code.

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection');
$collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

$collection = $collection
    ->addFieldToFilter('*')
    ->addStoreFilter()
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->setPageSize(10)
    ->setCurPage(1);

$collection->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft(
        'sales_flat_order_item AS order_item',
        'e.entity_id = order_item.product_id',
        'SUM(order_item.qty_ordered) AS ordered_qty')
    ->group('e.entity_id')
    ->order('ordered_qty DESC')
;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I currently have another implementation relying on a more procedural approach. It is not at all elegant, so I'll give your version a shot.