# Magento 1.8.0 THERE HAS BEEN AN ERROR PROCESSING YOUR REQUEST

Tags: mysql, magento

I have two exactly same sites, one is on local machine and one is live. When I'm trying to get best products into right sidebar the one that is on local machine is working fine but the live site throws the following error

```
a:5:{i:0;s:2382:"SELECT SUM(order_items.qty_ordered) AS `ordered_qty`, `order_items`.`name` AS `order_items_name`, `order_items`.`product_id` AS `entity_id`, `e`.`entity_type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`sku`, `e`.`has_options`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`created_at`, `e`.`updated_at`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`cost`, `e`.`created_at`, `e`.`enable_googlecheckout`, `e`.`gift_message_available`, `e`.`has_options`, `e`.`image_label`, `e`.`is_imported`, `e`.`is_recurring`, `e`.`links_exist`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`, `e`.`links_title`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`recurring_profile`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`shipment_type`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`sku`, `e`.`sku_type`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`updated_at`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`url_path`, `e`.`visibility`, `e`.`weight`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`msrp`, `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`msrp_enabled`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`small_image`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position` FROM `sales_flat_order_item` AS `order_items`
 INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order` AS `order` ON `order`.entity_id = order_items.order_id AND `order`.state  'canceled'
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON (e.type_id NOT IN ('grouped', 'configurable', 'bundle')) AND e.entity_id = order_items.product_id AND e.entity_type_id = 4
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='1' AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '2' WHERE (parent_item_id IS NULL) GROUP BY `order_items`.`product_id` HAVING (SUM(order_items.qty_ordered) > 0) ORDER BY `ordered_qty` desc LIMIT 9
```

";i:1;s:5232:"#0 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

#1 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)

#2 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)

#3 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT SUM(orde...', Array)

#4 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT SUM(orde...', Array)

#5 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(734): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT SUM(orde...', Array)

#6 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(734): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT SUM(orde...', Array)

#7 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1047): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT SUM(orde...')

#8 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(871): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_loadEntities(false, false)

#9 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(752): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->load()

#10/var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/app/design/frontend/default/ma_pharmacy/template/magentothem/bestsellerproductvertscroller/bestsellerright.phtml(42): Varien_Data_Collection->count()

#11 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')

#12 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')

#13 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()

#14 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(886): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()

#15 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()

#16 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(886): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()

#17 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(605): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()

#18 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(549): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('right', true)

#19 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/app/design/frontend/default/ma_pharmacy/template/page/2columns-right.phtml(59): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('right')

#20 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')

#21 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')

#22 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()

#23 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(886): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()

#24 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()

#25 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()

#26 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()

#27 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')

#28 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')

#29 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()

#30/var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')

#31 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))

#32 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()

#33 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)

#34 /var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')

#35 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}

I don't quite understand where is the problem. Would appreciate some help, where should I look.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: in the first place , why are you using manual query and not magento's ORM.http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-5-magento-models-and-orm-basics

Comment: I'm not using manual query.The theme requesting products via  Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract   public function getProducts () { $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection') .....}

Comment: in your file app/design/frontend/default/ma_pharmacy/template/magentothem/bestsellerproductvertscroller/bestsellerright.phtml , check what result is getting returned.

Comment: somehow the problem is in ->addOrderedQty() and ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc') once I removed it everything started to work. May be anyone has some thoughts regarding this issue?

Comment: Why downvote? How is it unclear or not useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said above the issue was in ->addOrderedQty() and ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc') the fix can be found here [Magento 1.7 sorting by ordered quantity - bestseller products issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893475/magento-1-7-sorting-by-ordered-quantity-bestseller-products-issues)

Answer (score 2):

use this steps

`system->config->catalog->frontend`

set `Use Flat Catalog Category`, `Use Flat Catalog Product` both to no.

It works for me.